# Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying the following code

```
Object.prototype.colorChange=function(element, index, array){
    console.log("e,l,m",element,index,array);
    element.style.background="blue";
}

document.getElementsByClassName("w3-margin-bottom").forEach(Object.prototype.colorChange);
```

which gives following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).forEach is not a function

Comment: **Please search before posting.** Just searching on the error message would have answered your question **immediately** by finding the earlier question and its answers here.

Comment: could u give me the reference where the question has been previously posted.

Comment: I already did, above, before posting that comment.

Comment: Hey @Crowder I wonder If you mentioned the link

Comment: Hey @Crowder I wonder If you mentioned the link